# Missing file icons in FileZilla

Tags: files, filezilla

File icons seem to be missing on my Ubuntu computer when using Filezilla (shows blank icon for every file) this doesn't seem to happen on Windows, is this intended or can I fix it somehow?

[image: filezilla]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is intended and has been for a while ([2010](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=16051)).

The themes you can pick in Filezilla itself do not work too. It is because of all the different methods different Linux systems use.

From the link:

> The stock icon, what users are seeing, is simply the file.png from the currently selected icon set in FileZilla, OpenCrystal by default.

---

This happens when I replace `/usr/share/filezilla/resources/opencrystal/16x16/file.png` with  `/usr/share/filezilla/resources/tango/16x16/file.png`:

[image]

The folder icons does change with the Ubuntu theme. So I assume our themes lack support for filezilla(?)